# MySQL delete multiple rows in one query conditions unique to each row

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, multiple-records

So I know in [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) it's possible to insert multiple rows in one query like so:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
```

I would like to delete multiple rows in a similar way. I know it's possible to delete multiple rows based on the exact same conditions for each row, i.e.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE col1='4' and col2='5'
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE col1 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

However, what if I wanted to delete multiple rows in one query, with each row having a set of conditions unique to itself? Something like this would be what I am looking for:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (col1,col2) IN (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You were very close, you can use this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (col1,col2) IN ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28eba/1).

Comment: Please note that in MySQL 5.6 this will perform poorly as tuple compares end up doing a table scan. You should prefer "WHERE (col1=1 AND col2=2) OR (col1=3 AND col2=4)..." for better performance. This is fixed in 5.7.

Comment: If anyone is curious, this is the bug that was fixed in 5.7.3 that @ep4169 references: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31188

Answer (score 13):

A slight extension to the answer given, so, hopefully useful to the asker and anyone else looking.

You can also `SELECT` the values you want to delete. But watch out for the Error 1093 - You can't specify the target table for update in FROM clause.

```
DELETE FROM
    orders_products_history
WHERE
    (branchID, action) IN (
    SELECT
        branchID,
        action
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            branchID,
            action
        FROM
            orders_products_history
        GROUP BY
            branchID,
            action
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 10000
        ) a
    );
```

I wanted to delete all history records where the number of history records for a single action/branch exceed 10,000. And thanks to this question and chosen answer, I can.

Hope this is of use.

Richard.

Comment: Formatting is to provide hierarchy and dependency. Sure 1 line of SQL would be the same but unreadable. Pretty much anything is better than a 1 liner. Of course, I use Whitesmith for my code and no one likes that either. "Too much white space" I hear them whine. Pah! I say. Use an IDE that formats it for YOUR preference for editing and to the repo's preference when you save. Oh... you use vi ... <sigh>! :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "Whitesmith"?

Comment: Whitesmith is a code formatting style https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style

Comment: wow that's an odd one. I don't quite remember anyone using it at all... How old are you?

Comment: Nearly 50. The way to think of it is if you used BASIC, Pascal, COBOL, then the BEGIN/END would always be on separate lines and indented. I just followed that when I want to {}. And as {} are around the compound statement, they are subordinate to the if()/while()/etc. so are indented. It is a logical choice, but just not very popular.

Answer (score -1):

Took a lot of googling but here is what I do in Python for MySql when I want to delete multiple items from a single table using a list of values.

```
#create some empty list
values = []
#continue to append the values you want to delete to it
#BUT you must ensure instead of a string it's a single value tuple
values.append(([Your Variable],))
#Then once your array is loaded perform an execute many
cursor.executemany("DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE ID = %s", values)
```

Comment: The question asks how to do it in MySQL without Python.