# node-mysql proper escaping for bulk deletes with unique criteria

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm am trying to prepare [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904067/mysql-delete-multiple-rows-in-one-query-conditions-unique-to-each-row) query using node-mysql.

The node-mysql [docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#performing-queries) suggest that nested arrays, e.g. `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` are converted to grouped lists, e.g. `(1, 2), (3, 4)`.  Along those lines, I set up my query as follows:

```
var sql = DELETE FROM collection_post WHERE (post_id, collection_id) IN (?)
var values = [[170, 2], [170, 7]]; // Generated programmatically.
```

Based on the rules specified in node-mysql, when I run

```
connection.query(sql, values, callback);
```

I assumed the resulting query would be:

```
DELETE FROM collection_post WHERE (post_id, collection_id) IN ((170, 2), (170, 7))
```

But when I actually perform the query I get this:

```
ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 2 column(s)
```

I tried removing the parentheses from the sql statement e.g.

```
var sql = DELETE FROM collection_post WHERE (post_id, collection_id) IN ?
```

but that results in a syntax error.  What's the proper formatting / escaping to get this query to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out awhile back and thought I'd post my answer here.  Turns out you have to wrap the values in another array.  So your query would look like this:

```
var sql = DELETE FROM collection_post WHERE (post_id, collection_id) IN (?);
```

and your values need to look like this:

```
var values = [[[170, 2], [170, 7]]];
```