# Multiple column and multiple criteria SQL Server Delete?

Tags: sql-server

I have tried everything to get this to work. I know it works for MySQL, but I am stumped as to how to get this to work in SQL Server.

Using the code from here: [MySQL delete multiple rows in one query conditions unique to each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904067/mysql-delete-multiple-rows-in-one-query-conditions-unique-to-each-row) and here [Fiddle MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bef6)

```
DELETE FROM tab 
WHERE (col1, col2) IN (('2016/3/1', 2), ('2016/3/2', 4), ('2016/3/3', 6));
```

I know you can do this below in SQL Server, but this only addresses one column.

```
DELETE FROM tab 
WHERE col2 IN (2, 4, 6);
```

[Fiddle SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03d51)

How can you achieve the same thing in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE tab
FROM tab 
JOIN (VALUES ('2016/3/1',2),('2016/3/2',4),('2016/3/3',6)) AS t(d, v)
  ON tab.col1 = t.d AND tab.col2 = t.v;
```

The query uses SQL Server's [**Table Value Constructor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) so as to create an in-line table that contains all of the criteria values.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25d66/1)