# MySQL Query Multiple Delete Values

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help. My eyes are going numb. My body weak.

**Attempt #9432**

Taken from this answer 
[MySQL delete multiple rows in one query conditions unique to each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904067/mysql-delete-multiple-rows-in-one-query-conditions-unique-to-each-row)

```
DELETE FROM `productimages` WHERE (`ID`,`imageURL`) 
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example1.jpg')
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example2.jpg')
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example3.jpg')
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example4.jpg')
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example5.jpg'))
```

Failed.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '((179,'https:// . . .

Referencing my archive, on 02/14/96 - on attempt #387 I discovered that you cannot use multiple `WHERE` clauses in one query. I next tried

**Attempt #837**

```
DELETE FROM `productimages` (WHERE `productID` = 179 AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example1.jpg') 
(AND `productID` = 179 AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example2.jpg')
(AND `productID` = 179 AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example3.jpg')
(AND `productID` = 179 AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example4.jpg')
(AND `productID` = 179 AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example5.jpg') 
(AND `productID` = 179 AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example6.jpg')
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(WHERE 'productID' = 179 AND 'imageURL' = 'https:// . . .

A more recent attempt, my closest yet:

**Attempt #10473**

```
DELETE FROM `productimages` 
WHERE `productID` = 179 
AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example1.jpg' 
AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example2.jpg' 
AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example3.jpg' 
AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example4.jpg' 
AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example5.jpg' 
AND `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example6.jpg'
```

Indescribable joy. A successfully query.

Upon closer look...

> 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0128 seconds.)

Again, defeated.

Has anyone gotten this far yet?
You'd think there'd be a manual or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to check for the value of a tuple with an `IN` condition. You just have syntax errors.

Syntax is as follows :

```
DELETE FROM `productimages` 
WHERE (`productID`,`imageURL`) IN (
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example1.jpg'),
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example2.jpg'),
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example3.jpg'),
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example4.jpg'),
    (179,'http://www.example.com/example5.jpg')
)
```

This is quite a flexible way to filter records, and would fit the case where there several different `ID`s in the tuples. Efficiency, however, will decrease with the number of tuples in the list, and eventually reach a system limit. To process a *very large* list, you would better consider using a temp table that you can simply join with.

Comment: Remarkable.  It was my mistake leaving the `ID` in Attempt #9432, it should have been `productID` as the rest.  With that said, `WHERE productID = 179` in your query can be removed, along with a replace of the `AND` with `WHERE`, finally additionally adding a comma `),` as the first to every other but the last, and .. it works.  It finally works.  Thank you @GMB. Thank you.

Comment: @bbruman : welcome ! I fixed my answer accordingly (you could have edited it directly, too).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `WHERE` clause you are asking to delete where the id is one value **and** the image url is all the other values **at the same time**.

What you need to do is use `OR` for each value of the `imageURL`:

```
DELETE FROM `productimages` WHERE `productID` = 179 AND (
  `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example1.jpg' 
  OR `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example2.jpg' 
  OR `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example3.jpg' 
  OR `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example4.jpg' 
  OR `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example5.jpg' 
  OR `imageURL` = 'http://www.example.com/example6.jpg'
)
```

You can also use the `IN` operator:

```
DELETE FROM `productimages` 
WHERE `productID` = 179 AND `imageURL` IN (
  'http://www.example.com/example1.jpg', 
  'http://www.example.com/example2.jpg', 
  'http://www.example.com/example3.jpg', 
  ...
)
```

**Also:** The reason your first one isn't working is because you are missing a parentheses and commas.

```
DELETE FROM `productimages` WHERE (`ID`,`imageURL`) (
  (179,'http://www.example.com/example1.jpg'),
  (179,'http://www.example.com/example2.jpg'),
  (179,'http://www.example.com/example3.jpg'),
  (179,'http://www.example.com/example4.jpg'),
  (179,'http://www.example.com/example5.jpg'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempts @Ibu.  Your first query worked to delete one image (the first one), but no others.  Your second had the same result as my last one, no error, but 0 rows affected.

Comment: Close on the third.  Thank you again.  I'll add three more attempts to the book.